# Strange behavior with PHP string concatenation

Tags: php

I was debugging a MySQL query when I found this strange bug/feature:

```
echo 'a'.'a'; // aa

echo 'a'.'<a'; // a (expecting a<a)

echo 'a'.'<a>'; // a<a>

echo 'a'.'<'; // a<
```

Why is PHP behaving like this? I found a few similar questions on SO having to do with outputting HTML as text without encoding. I'm viewing the output as text, not HTML, and the `<a` still isn't appearing.

I tried this on 2 different PHP environments running PHP 5.3 or 5.4, they all behaved this way.

If it helps, here's the line that made me discover bug/feature:

```
$query.=' FROM links WHERE '.$results[0]['date'].'<date ';
```

**EDIT:
READ THE QUESTION, PEOPLE.**

I'm viewing the output as a string, not HTML. If PHP automatically parses string literals, then there's something seriously wrong with PHP.

And for people recommending `&lt;`, why do you expect that to work for MySQL.

**EDIT 2: Forget the browser.**

I ran this in Windows CMD and it's outputting exactly what I typed above. If you're convinced that I'm stupid and I'm not seeing the `<a` because I'm viewing it as HTML, READ THE QUESTION and you'll see that `echo 'a'.'<a>';` outputs `a<a>`.

I just tried it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and the `<a` is appearing as expected. Seems like it has to do with my computer, I'm using WampServer 2.4.

Comment: Because it renders html, prepend it with `<pre>` or viewsource.

Comment: Are you using a browser to execute the script? Then, your browser is trying to interpret it as HTML...

Comment: READ THE QUESTION. Why would I use `<pre>` in a MySQL query?

Comment: For all you people upvoting the `<pre>` comment, try executing this, maybe all 3 of my servers are messed up: `echo '<pre>'.'<a'.'</pre>';`. It output `<pre></pre>` for me.

Comment: What are you viewing this output in, then? PHP does not "interpret" text for you, except to replace any variables it might find in a `"`-quoted string. PHP is dumping out EXACTLY what you gave it. If you're viewing this in a browser, then the browser BY DEFAULT will assume you're sending html. If you want to view it as text, do a "view source", send over a text/plain content-type, or DON'T USE A BROWSER

Comment: I'm slightly confused in what you're asking. To me, it seems like you want to echo the sql string to verify that it's doing what you want. if you're just debugging it, use

    "<pre><code>". htmlspecialchars($sql)."</code></pre>";

Comment: I ran this in a terminal and it still outputted `<pre></pre>`. What part of "I'm viewing the output as text, not HTML" do you guys not understand? Even MySQL is spitting out errors because of this; it has nothing to do with a browser.

Comment: Could you show us the query you are trying to debug, after variables are set, etc

Comment: Then show the actual query you're generating, and the exact error message you're getting. We can't help you if you don't give us the entire picture.

Comment: Query: `SELECT SUM(IF(318418040<=date AND date<=318437200,1,0)) FROM links WHERE 318347783` from `echo $query;`. `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_info()` both aren't returning anything. By the way, I'm using `SUM(IF...)` because I'm generating the query in a for loop.

Comment: "I was debugging a MySQL query when I found ..." - how were you debugging it? They don't look like MySQL commands to me, but I'm not a database guy.

Comment: "Why is PHP behaving like this..." - Oops, strike the earlier question. How are you observing it? Is it in a browser, or from another output? If from a browser, you might try "View Source" (or equivalent) to ensure its not he browser mucking up your results.

Comment: "Seems like it has to do with my computer..." - that question might be closed for "unable to duplicate or typographical error". Don't get upset.

Answer (score 3):

Putting this here, since it'll be horribly ugly in a comment. This is directly from PHP-cli:

```
php > echo 'a'.'a'; // aa
aa
php > echo 'a'.'<a'; // a (expecting a<a)
a<a
php > echo 'a'.'<a>'; // a<a>
a<a>
php > echo 'a'.'<'; // a<
a<
```

It's literally a cut&paste of your code above, and as you can see, what you're expecting is EXACTLY what PHP outputs.

If you're not getting this, then YOU are doing something DIFFERENTLY.

Comment: I think 'the question is wrong', here is the proof, is a correct\valid answer.

Comment: How would this be a "proof"? It's running as expected on his computer, not mine. At least I now know it's not an universal issue, thanks Marc.

Comment: i don't think any one actully believes you @Linksku, not that we think you are deliberately misleading us, just that something you have yet to share is going on.

Comment: Well, you're blaming PHP for something which absolutely is not possible in PHP. It's not its job to filter your strings for "valid" html... especially when PHP can generate so many OTHER things that AREN'T html. If something is stripping off those "invalid tags", then that's something wrapping around PHP, or something that's been inserted into PHP as a non-standard filter. Out-of-the-box PHP cannot ever do something like this.

Comment: As I said, it has NOTHING to do with HTML. @Dagon: I think it's just a bug with my version of PHP, version 5.5.8. I flipped the query to make it `date>...`, and it's working fine.

Comment: You need to show what you're doing with this query string. It's obviously NOT html, but obviously something is mangling it... so show your actual "build the sql" and "execute the query" code.

Comment: I made a file with just `<?php echo 'a'.'<a';` and the error is still occurring. So it's just a bug with either my version of PHP or my computer, someone can close the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `<` in the echo in question with `&lt;`

```
echo 'a'.'&lt;a';
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar behaviour, where using the concat operator would trim away contents, incidentally also beginning with <. The apache error log revealed that the script caused a segmentation fault.

I couldn't reproduce it in a test script, so I figured the concat operation problem was not the source but a symptom.

Turned out that we made operations through PECL ssh2 earlier in the same script, which caused the segfault and subsequently messed up what happened further down the line.

So my suggestion would be to check the error log and look for indirect causes of the problem.